# Is it possible to to catch all possible errors/exception?

Tags: java, swing, exception, try-catch

I have a Java Swing program with many classes. I do use try-catchs where they are required, but no where else. I also have a logger class, which writes to a file when an exception is caught. It prints out the stack trace and the message.

I want to be able to log every exception but without putting try-catch's everywhere. Is this possible?

-- EDIT (My main method) --

```
public class Bacon extends Thread implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    public static Bacon instance = null;
    private JFrame main;

    private Bacon() {
        main = new JFrame("Bacon");
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        main.addWindowListener(new WindowEventHandler());
        setLAF();
        main.setSize(Constants.MAIN_DIMENSION);
        main.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        main.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        main.setIconImage(getIcon());
        setUserName();
        setUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);

        main.setJMenuBar(Menu.getInstance());
        main.setContentPane(getMainPanel());
        main.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static Bacon getInstance() {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new Bacon();

        return instance;
    }

    private JPanel getMainPanel() {
        JPanel main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        main.add(Tabs.getInstance(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        main.add(StatusBar.getInstance(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        return main;
    }

    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            getInstance();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            ErrorLogging.log(t.getStackTrace(), t.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        ErrorLogging.log(e.getStackTrace(), e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely!

Look at the Thread class' method setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler.

[Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)

Comment: I've tried implementing UncaughtExceptionHandler and extending Thread, and then used setUncaughtExceptionHandler, but I was not able to successfully log any errors that happened in another class. I've posted a small snippet of my main .java class in the original post. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: You don't have to extend Thread to implement an UncaughtExceptionHandler. You can create an anonymous class. setUncaughtExceptionHandler is a static method, you should be able to pass in an anonymous class, and just log the throwable passed to the method.

Comment: is it possible to have a non static class inside a static method? I tried and eclipse wouldn't let me. Here's my main with setUncaughtExceptionHandler in it. http://pastebin.com/CiwHeET9

Comment: Apologies, I gave the wrong method. It is setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler. That one is static. It should catch all Uncaught exceptions from any thread. But according to the doc, it is called right before the Thread dies. Not sure if this is the behavior you desire.

Comment: Just remember, setUncaughtExceptionHandker only works within the same thread group, otherwise it's a fantastic solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer Good call! But reading the method's javadoc gives an explanation. It states the the order of handling an uncaught exception is the following: 1. Thread 2. ThreadGroup 3. Default handler. "If the thread does not have an explicit uncaught exception handler set, and the thread's thread group (including parent thread groups) does not specialize its uncaughtException method, then the default handler's uncaughtException method will be invoked."

Comment: I had the same confusion as well. There's a difference between the setUncaughtExceptionHandler, which is a member function, and the setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler, which is a static class function.

Answer (score 5):

You catch as much as your try encapsulates, so in your main method put a surrounding try block and catch(Throwable) to assure you catch everything that can be thrown.

It's usually a better idea to handle exceptions individually as they occur though.

Comment: *"It's a better idea to handle exceptions individually as they occur though."* - I'd call that bad advice.  The best thing to do really depends on the circumstances.  For instance, it is often better to let exceptions propagate to a point where they can be properly handled.

Comment: @StephenC You don't agree that a _better_ idea than catching everything in the main method is to catch and handle exceptions as they occur?

Comment: I believe neither of those alternatives is always better, and that there are OTHER alternatives too.  This makes your advice over-simplistic and therefore bad.

Comment: @StephenC Edited to reflect the fact that not always is it a better idea. I do submit that _usually_ it is.

Comment: @StephenC, I've tried putting a try-catch within the main method. It is able to catch all errors which happen within that class, but if an exception is thrown else where, then that exception is not logged. I've posted a small glimpse of my code above in the original post, let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle the exceptions that you want to not crash the program, otherwise you can just catch(Throwable) in your main method.

Comment: Not the best way to go. Look at Runtime class' setUncaughtExceptionHandler method!

Comment: This will give you the ability to log them, but it's not a substitute for "putting try-catch's everywhere" as he is asking, they need to be caught and handled properly still.

Comment: @RockyTriton I put a try catch in my main method, and it is successful in catching all errors which happen within that specific class, but if an exception is thrown elsewhere it is not caught and logged.

Comment: Where are those other classes being called from?  Are they being called from the event thread?

Comment: IMO, setting an UncaughtExceptionHandler answers his question "I want to be able to log every exception but without putting try-catch's everywhere. Is this possible?". Also, checked exceptions SHOULD be caught and handled somewhere in his code. The compiler will enforce this. As for unchecked (RuntimeExceptions) this is not necessary. Look at Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Chapter 9, Item 58 for advice on this.

Comment: @RockyTriton, I've added a glimpse of my main .java file to the original post. Let me know if you need anything else. These other classes are extending JPanel which are put into a JTabbedPane. The main JTabbedPane class is set in the Bacon.java (main .java file) which is set in the method getMainPanel().

Answer (score 3):

Possible, not advised.

You can make every method throw an `Exception` and every method that calls that method will also have to throw one.

The point of having those try catch blocks is so that you can narrow down exactly where the problem is caused. They are meant to help you, not hurt you.